# How do I add a username to a firebase child without deleting the others or using "push()"?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am trying to tabulate users within a specific GPS cell in my app. They may leave that cell or return at any point. The issue I am having is I am using `push()` which creates a unique key each time. I have tried setting the value to `null` but it does not get all cells.

The users address is converted to GPS coordinates when account is created. This is the "grid" value returned from `getGrid()`. Then the code pulls all cells surrounding that grid and creates a matrix of those. Then the UID is added to those cells to represent their service areas in order to match them with other users.

My goal is to have each of the numbered child directories in Firebase to only have UID without a key and without removing any other data. Any help would be appreciated.

```
public void changeProviderServiceCells(int oldRadius) {

        Truck truck = MainActivity.mUser.getTruck();

        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        oldGridRadius = getProvidersRadius(oldRadius, MainActivity.mUser.getGrid());

       DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(MainActivity.GPS_PATH);

        for (int x = 0; x < oldGridRadius.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < oldGridRadius.length; y++) {
                String gridString = String.valueOf(oldGridRadius[y][x]);
                ref.child(String.valueOf(oldGridRadius[y][x])).removeValue();
            }
        }

        gridRadius = getProvidersRadius(truck.getRadius(),
                MainActivity.mUser.getGrid());
        MainActivity.matrix = gridRadius.clone();
        //MainActivity.firstGPSRequest = false;


        for (int x = 0; x < gridRadius.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridRadius.length; y++) {

                DatabaseReference db =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(MainActivity.GPS_PATH)
                        .child(String.valueOf(gridRadius[y][x]));

                db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                            userList.add(String.valueOf(ds.getValue()));
                        }

                        if (!userList.contains(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                            db.push().setValue(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I figured this out on my own. I was overthinking the issue. I simply restructured the data to avoid using a random key by making the child the UID and just assigning a value of 1.

```
public void changeProviderServiceCells(int oldRadius) {

        Truck truck = MainActivity.mUser.getTruck();

        FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        oldGridRadius = getProvidersRadius(oldRadius, MainActivity.mUser.getGrid());

       DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(MainActivity.GPS_PATH);

        for (x = 0; x < oldGridRadius.length; x++) {
            for (y = 0; y < oldGridRadius.length; y++) {
                ref.child(String.valueOf(oldGridRadius[y][x])).child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())
                        .removeValue();

            }
        }

        gridRadius = getProvidersRadius(truck.getRadius(),
                MainActivity.mUser.getGrid());
        MainActivity.matrix = gridRadius.clone();
        //MainActivity.firstGPSRequest = false;


        for (int x = 0; x < gridRadius.length; x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < gridRadius.length; y++) {

                DatabaseReference db =  FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference(MainActivity.GPS_PATH)
                        .child(String.valueOf(gridRadius[y][x])).child(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid());

                db.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {

                        ArrayList<String> userList = new ArrayList<String>();
                        for (DataSnapshot ds: snapshot.getChildren()){
                            userList.add(String.valueOf(ds.getValue()));
                        }

                        if (!userList.contains(auth.getCurrentUser().getUid())){
                            db.setValue(1)
                                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                                        }
                                    }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                }
                            });
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

                    }
                });
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).